# Handling super() in Multiple Inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, super

As per [Guido's explanation on MRO](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html). In the following example (Python 3 syntax)

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
...         print("Am in A")
...         super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
...         print("Am in B")
...         super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> class C(A,B): #MRO - C, A, B, Object
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         print("Am in C")
...         super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> class D(B,A): #MRO - D, B, A, Object
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         print("Am in D")
...         super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
...
```

super() needs to be called from both base classes A & B in order to complete MRO of derived classes C & D i.e.

C's MRO - C, A, B, Object
From C's init-> C's super() invokes A's init 
From A's init-> A's super() invokes B's init

D's MRO - D, B, A, Object
From D's init-> D's super() invokes B's init 
From B's init-> B's super() invokes A's init

However this resulted in broken initialization,

```
>>> C(1,2)
Am in C
Am in A
Am in B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Because, from B's init-> B's super() invokes "object"'s init which doesn't take arguments

Calling D(1,2) will produce similar error

If I remove super() from B, the D's MRO (D,B,A, Object) will stop at B. A's init will never be invoked.

```
>>> C(1,2)
Am in C
Am in A
Am in B
<__main__.C object at 0x7ffb07b038d0>
>>> D(1,2)
Am in D
Am in B
<__main__.D object at 0x7ffb07b03908>
>>>
```

I can solve this by checking super class (both in A & B) before calling it's init

```
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        print("Am in A")
        if super().__doc__ != "The most base type":
            super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: As suggested in comments, we should have a top level class which doesn't call `super()`

Is this really necessary? why can't the `object` class allow optional arguments (`*args, **kwargs`) to favour flexible base class ordering during multiple inheritance?

because object's `__init__` has just pass statement

```
class object:
    def __init__(self): # known special case of object.__init__
        """ x.__init__(...) initializes x; see help(type(x)) for signature """
        pass
```

Comment: Why not insert a single class at the "top" of the "diamond", then you can implement `__init__` however you like.

Comment: As I understand it, the correct use of `super` for a method requires that there be a single class which is the final arbiter for that method, and that class's implementation does *not* call `super`. That class must also be the final class in the MRO. Unfortunately, as you have noticed, `object` does not correctly act as that arbiter for the magic methods.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I agree we can solve by having a single class at the top, which does not call super() to avoid this problem. I am still curious to know,  will there be any impact in allowing optional args in object class ?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't expect your classes to work right if you pass in extra arbitrary arguments. You wouldn't expect `list([], 2, 3, 4)` to work, would you? If you have specific arguments that belong to some of the classes, you should accept those arguments by name in those classes, and *not pass them on* in your `super` call. Keyword-only arguments are a good idea if you don't want to get stuck with an awkward MRO-dependent argument order.